# Registered users in new Firebase Spark Plan

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Are there any limitations on the number of users that are being registered when using the free plan of Firebase?

Comment: There is no limit on the number of *registered* users.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank. I have doubts about it since google take over Firebase because registered users are limited in their free plan previously until now.

Comment: There has *never* been a limit on how many users can be *registered*. There has *always* been a limit to how many users can be *connected* to the database simultaneously on free plans.

Comment: Hmm, I see, well I'll be damned. Thank you for the information, Frank. Great help!